# Collapsing dynamically added tabs in accordion

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

Here is a sample.

```js
$(function() {
        var icons = {
            header: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-e",
            headerSelected: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-s"
        };
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
            icons: icons,
            collapsible: true
        });
        $( "#header1" ).click(function(e) { return false;
            $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "icons", false );
        });
});

$('#accordion .accClicked')
        .off('click')
    .click(function(){
        $(this).next().toggle('fast');
    });

    $('#add').click(function() {
       var $tab="<h3 id='header3' class='accClicked'><a href='#'>Section 3</a></h3><div>Bonjour Stackoverflow</div>";
       $('#accordion').append($tab);

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="accordion">
    <h3 id="header1" class="accClicked"><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3>
    <div> Good Morning Stackoverflow</div>
    <h3 id="header2" class="accClicked"><a href="#">Section 2</a></h3>
    <div>Buongiorno Stackoverflow</div>
    <h3 id="header3" class="accClicked"><a href="#">Section 3</a></h3>
    <div>Bonjour Stackoverflow</div>
</div>

<button id="add">
 Add tab
</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xso14hct/

I can add a new tab but I can not collapse it. I searched and found that I should somehow update DOM, but I just didn't find how can I do it.

I could simply use a jquery-ui accordion, but the problem is, that it automatically closes opened tabs when you open another tab, but I don't need that. Here is a link to it: [JQuery-UI Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#collapsible)

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign handlers to the new tab. Check this

```
$(function() {
  var icons = {
    header: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-e",
    headerSelected: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-s"
  };
  $("#accordion").accordion({
    icons: icons,
    collapsible: true
  });
  $("#header1").click(function(e) {
    return false;
    $("#accordion").accordion("option", "icons", false);
  });
});

$('#accordion .accClicked')
  .off('click')
  .click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggle('fast');
  });

var i = 4;
$('#add').click(function() {
  var $tab = "<h3 id='header" + i + "' class='accClicked'><a href='#'>Section " + i + "</a></h3><div>Bonjour Stackoverflow</div>";
  $('#accordion').append($tab);
  $('#accordion .accClicked')
    .off('click')
    .click(function() {
      $(this).next().toggle('fast');
    });
  i++;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the click rewrite into a function and run it again for each tab you add:

```
$(function() {
    var icons = {
        header: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-e",
        headerSelected: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-s"
    };
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        icons: icons,
        collapsible: true
    });
    $("#header1").click(function(e) {
        return false;
        $("#accordion").accordion("option", "icons", false);
    });
});

// from here we change to:
function resetTabClick() {
    $('#accordion .accClicked')
        .off('click').click(function(){
            $(this).next().toggle('fast');
    });
}
resetTabClick();

$('#add').click(function() {
       var $tab="<h3 id='header3' class='accClicked'><a href='#'>Section 3</a></h3><div>Bonjour Stackoverflow</div>";
       $('#accordion').append($tab);

       resetTabClick();

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are very close.  You just need to wrap your callback function for the tabs in a function, so that you can call it when you add a new tab to the DOM.

Also, add a style of `display: none;`, if you want new tabs to be initially closed.

```js
$(function() {
    var icons = {
        header: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-e",
        headerSelected: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-s"
    };
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        icons: icons,
        collapsible: true
    });
    $("#header1").click(function(e) {
        return false;
        $("#accordion").accordion("option", "icons", false);
    });
});

function makeNewTab() {
    $('#accordion .accClicked')
        .off('click').click(function(){
            $(this).next().toggle('fast');
    });
}

$('#add').click(function() {
       var $tab="<h3 id='header3' class='accClicked'><a href='#'>Section 3</a></h3><div style='display:none;'>Bonjour Stackoverflow</div>";
       $('#accordion').append($tab);
       makeNewTab();

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="accordion">
    <h3 id="header1" class="accClicked"><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3>
    <div> Good Morning Stackoverflow</div>
    <h3 id="header2" class="accClicked"><a href="#">Section 2</a></h3>
    <div>Buongiorno Stackoverflow</div>
    <h3 id="header3" class="accClicked"><a href="#">Section 3</a></h3>
    <div>Bonjour Stackoverflow</div>
</div>

<button id="add">
 Add tab
</button>
```